# predict end position of circular movement

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a car at $(x_i, y_i)$ in a $2D$ plane, looking $(x_c, y_c)$.

In $1$ second, the car can move $1$ unit and turn $90º$ (while moving).

Given $(x_i, y_i)$, $(x_c, y_c)$ and the angle $\theta$ it must turn, how can I predict its end position $(x_f, y_f)$?

---

Example: the car is at $(0,0)$, looking $(0,1)$ and $\theta = -90º$:
[image]

As it moves $1$ unit in $1$ second and $90º$ is a quarter of a circle, it's easy to see that $2\pi r/4 = 1$ and find the radius.

If $\theta$ is not $90º$, one can find how much the car moves with a simple rule: $90º \rightarrow 1u, \theta \rightarrow x \implies x = \theta/90º$

My problem is when the car is looking into a wierd angle.

Comment: In one second, does it moves 1 unit (the lenght of the arc) or it moves exactly 90º? Note that the radius may be calculated different in each case.

Comment: In 1 second, it can do both. The car speed is constant. It walks 1 unit per second and 1 second is also the time necessary to rotate 90º. If the car moves in a straight line, it moves 1 unit, if it is making a curve, 1 second is the time it needs to rotate 90º, and as the speed is constant, it will still move 1 unit, but not in a straight line, but an arc instead. Is it clear?

Comment: 1 unit of distance or of time?

Comment: The car only rotates while it is moving. If it is moving, 1 second is the time it needs to rotate 90º. The speed is constant, that's why the blue arc in the exemple has a length of 1 unit.

Answer (score 1):

The equations of a circumference in parametric form is
$$x=x_c+R·cos(\theta) \tag {1}$$
$$y=y_c-R·sin(\theta)$$
where $x_c, y_c$ are the coordinates of the centre, and $\theta$ is the angle as rotation goes clockwise.

You must define as the origin the point $\{x_c+R, \; y_c\}$ so as the parametric form above works well.

We know that the car moves along a $\pi/2$ arc-lenght in one second, and also that that lenght is $1$.

Because arc lenght $L=R·\theta$ then $1=R·\pi/2)$ and then $R={2\over \pi}$

At some time the car is at $x_1,y_1$ and heading $x_2,y_2$. The vector of this movement is $\{x_2-x_1,\;y_2-y_1\}$, and a perpendicular vector to this, heading the center of the circumference is $\{y_1-y_2,\;x_2-x_1\}$

Let's normalize (vector with lenght =$1$) this perpendicular
$$x_p= \frac{y_1-y_2}{\sqrt {(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2}}$$ 
$$y_p= \frac{x_2-x_1}{\sqrt {(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2}}$$

The center is easily found by
$$x_c= x+R·x_p$$
$$y_c= y+R·y_p$$

The angle $\theta$ can be defined as a function of time due to we know the speed $\omega = \pi/2/second$
So
$$\theta = t·\pi/2 \tag{2}$$

If you know the time $t$, that's all.

 If you know $\{x,y\}$ and the heading then, after finding the center with the formulas above, substitute in $(1)$ and find $\theta$ (there may be a $\pi/2$ error, so choose the correct angle).

Finally, after $1$ second the car moves $\pi/2$ so the new angle is $\theta_t= \theta+\pi/2$. Use this $\theta_t$ in $(1)$ and you get where the car is after this last $1$ second.